# How to do binding in WPF - C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ViewItemTemplate"
                             TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" x:Name="CkBox">
                            <CkBox.IsChecked>
                                <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                     Mode="TwoWay">
                                    <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                        <RelativeSource Mode="TemplatedParent" />
                                    </Binding.RelativeSource>
                                </Binding>
                            </CkBox.IsChecked>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InvalidForeground}" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="CkBoxVisual" Property="Foreground" Value="#999999"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

How can i bind InvalidForeground? I looked online for many example they tell to use DataTemplate. But when i add DataTemplate above StackPanel i get errors? Am i doing something wrong?

I am trying to bind InvalidForeground so i can add some code to it. I am getting an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'InvalidForeground' due to unknown DataContext.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you asking? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I am trying to bind InvalidForeground so i can add some code to it. I am getting an error: Cannot resolve symbol 'InvalidForeground' due to unknown DataContext.

Comment: You are trying to bind `InvalidForeground`. But what is it? Where is it defined? And what do you mean by "so i can add some code to it"??

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - InvalidForeground is just a bool which will take true or false. I want to add property in code to take that value and change ForegroundColor of Checkbox text in design.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InvalidForeground}" Value="true">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ViewItemTemplate"
                         TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" x:Name="CkBox">
                <CkBox.IsChecked>
                    <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                 Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding.RelativeSource>
                            <RelativeSource Mode="TemplatedParent" />
                        </Binding.RelativeSource>
                    </Binding>
                </CkBox.IsChecked>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InvalidForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="CkBoxVisual" Property="Foreground" Value="#999999"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </CheckBox>
            <ContentPresenter />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        abc A = new abc();
        A.InvalidForeground = true;
    }
}
public class abc : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool invalidForeGround;
     public bool InvalidForeground
    {
        get
        { return invalidForeGround; }
        set
        { 
            invalidForeGround = value;
            Notify("InvalidForeground");
        }
     }
     private void Notify(string propName)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
     }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

InvalidForeground must be the property in the DataContext of the Control whose template the above code is.I hope this will help

Comment: I am trying to bind InvalidForeground to class: abc lets say. How can i do that? Any idea?

Comment: public class abc { public bool InvalidForeground { get; set; }}

Comment: So how can i make this change? I want to create an instance of class abc and change the InvalidForeground color property of that instance?

Comment: where you want to create instance of abc?

Comment: Updated the answer and specified the mode findparent

Comment: sorry still same error. One more question instead of window can i specify class abc directly? like AncestorType={x:Type abc}

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to declare a customized checkbox control to use within WPF application.  As such, your "InvalidForeground" property would be exposed, but the template doesn't understand what its real type is expected.

I've posted another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319) which gave a full step-by-step for a custom button.  The principles are the same, and I've tried to point out my understanding of of the declarations, the type, etc.  Hopefully it can guide you on not just this, but other class templates too.

Comment: I am trying to bind InvalidForeground to class: abc lets say. How can i do that? Any idea?

Comment: As the link in the above answer "here", it shows step by step.  You have much of the components / properties, but take a look at that and see if it helps you out.  You have to define your template of your class type so it can resolve properly and know what properties IT has, then it should find it for binding.  Let me know AFTER you've had a chance to review it.  A button template is more complex than a checkbox, but you'll see the parallels I'm sure.