# How to define a custom class of a control, and define custom events and handlers in it (in WPF)?

Tags: wpf, winforms, events, inheritance

I'm new to WPF and Windows Forms. I need to know how I could define a custom class of a control (e.g. a Label or a TextBox...) and define it's looks **AND** write my custom methods for any desired event of that control. Like putting a black border around a label, when clicked.

I need to do all this **SO** that I can dynamically create as many instances of that class as I want, making sure that they all have the same functionality and the look that I put in them.

Is there any simple tutorial about this ?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is to either inherit from a already existing control (CustomControl) os Creating a new control, and you can add a control into that (UserControl). If it's just supposed to be a custom class of one control (like a Label or a TextBox) then I would try to solve it with a CustomControl

The name are the same for WinForms and WPF. I could provide some links, but I think it's better that you just google it so you can find the example / tutorial that suits your needs the most.

*EDIT*

Ok, so I'd say that - depending on your background - WinForms is a little more simple. However WPF is probably the way to go if your making a professional program. (WinForms is kind of getting old)

**WinForm**

Here, at least, is a very short and simple example of a WinForm CustomControl:

```
namespace BorderLabelWinForms
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Drawing;

    public class BorderLabel : Label
    {
        private bool _showBorder = false;

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _showBorder = !_showBorder;
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
            this.Refresh();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (_showBorder)
            {
                Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 2.0f);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, this.ClientRectangle);
                pen.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can go from there and just extend it.

**WPF**

WPF is more complicated, but to create a CustomControl you right click the project in the project view, and choose Add > New Item. In the dialog that pops up, select a Custom Control (WPF). Now you will get a new {choosen name}.cs (in my example BorderLable) and a directory; Themes and a Generic.xaml file.
The Generic file is a Resource that describes how the control is built. For example here I have added a Label in the CustomControl:

Generic.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BorderLabel}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <local:ThicknessAndBoolToThicknessConverter x:Key="tabttc" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BorderLabel}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" >
                        <Border.BorderThickness>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource tabttc}" >
                                <Binding Path="BorderThickness" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                <Binding Path="ShowBorder" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.BorderThickness>
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

BorderLable.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BorderButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bla. bla bla...
    /// </summary>
    public class BorderLabel : Label
    {
        //DependencyProperty is needed to connect to the XAML
        public bool ShowBorder
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowBorderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowBorderProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowBorderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowBorder", typeof(bool), typeof(BorderLabel), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        //Override OnMouseUp to catch the "Click". Toggle Border visibility
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            ShowBorder = !ShowBorder;
        }

        //Contructor (some default created when selecting new CustomControl)
        static BorderLabel()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BorderLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BorderLabel)));
        }
    }

    //So doing it the WPF way, I wanted to bind the thickness of the border
    //to the selected value of the border, and the ShowBorder dependency property
    public class ThicknessAndBoolToThicknessConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[0] is Thickness && values[1] is bool)
            {
                Thickness t = (Thickness)values[0];
                bool ShowBorder = (bool)values[1];

                if (ShowBorder)
                    return t;
                else
                    return new Thickness(0.0d);

            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And at last you have to add the control to your MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="BorderButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BorderButton"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Note that the BorderThickness has to be set to something! -->
        <local:BorderLabel Content="HelloWorld" Margin="118,68,318,218" MouseUp="BorderLabel_MouseUp" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" ShowBorder="False" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see the WPF is somewhat more complex... Anyway, now you have two examples to start from! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I read a brief blog about the difference between these two, but the blog is too brief !
I think both CustomControl and UserControl will do the purpose for me in this particular situation...
I'm googling things right now. But if you have any link or post or anything regarding this, please share them with me. Much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319) of a previous answer I posted.  Someone was interested in a button and custom properties / settings.  It also shows how I started sampling and learning controls, customizing templates, etc and taking advantage of said properties.  You can expand this by working with events via "Triggers" (associated with dependency properties that you can bind to).

I'm sure you'll find many other samples out there, but this will probably help you not hurt your head banging the wall in the mean-time :)

Comment: thanks for your help. but DependencyProperties is confusing for me :D
And CustomControl will do fine for me ;)