# Understanding Templates

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm struggling with Templates in WPF

I understand the concept in that I can have a control, and 'override' the ContentTemplate (or similar). I use it often with the TabControl

However, I don't understand it in terms of what the initial control looked like. And if we are limited on the names. EG, could we build a control and overwrite the NonsenseNameTemplate?

If I were to build my own UserControl and provide the ability for people to override things like my NonsenseNameTemplate, what would this code look like?

My guess, with pseudo code would be

```
<UserControl>
    <NonsenseNameTempalte>
            //some resources
            //some other controls
    </NonsenseNameTempalte>
</UserControl>
```

In the above example, I can fully understand how I could create a new control and overwrite the NonsenseNameTemplate but I can't see any code examples of the UserControl and it's usage.

Comment: If you use blend, you can create a new template, and it will use the original content as starting point.

Comment: I do not have blend sadly

Comment: I just wonder. If you want them to template you class like the framework ones, should you not use a Control instead of CustomControl ? Can anybody confirm whether this is true? 
http://wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx

Comment: I have seen that link @MauriceStam, but it doesn't fully answer the question about naming the templates (or if it does, I didn't undesrtand it). Thank you though for helping :) The example that are shown for things like <Setter Property="Control.Template">  - I understand how this works, but not how to make my own

Comment: Just for clarity before I answer. Is the following your scenario?...

You are building a custom control, with its own properties (or you may want it to have), and give it a template which it will use by default. Then, when people are using this control, they can choose to use its template property to drop in their own template when needed to customise the controls appearance?~

Also, from your initial post, I believe Maurice is correct in that you may be after a Control rather than UserControl.

Comment: @GavinLanata, that is a perfect description of what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template(v=vs.110).aspx) is nothing more than a (dependency) property. By writing

```
<Button>
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      ...
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>y
```

you are doing nothing more than creating a new instance of `ControlTemplate` class and assigning it to `Button.Template` property of that specific button. Each control has it's own `ControlTemplate` saved somewhere in it's assembly. It is generally not so simple to actually get those default templates, but Blend can help with it.

Of course, you can create your won `NonsenseNameTemplate` property, but actually using it would require some deep knowledge of WPF composition, layouting and rendering. Which is usually not required for normal usage of WPF. And I agree that there is not a much online resources about doing something like this, for exactly this reason.

Comment: Wow... I feel some what happy it's easy to understand yet cheated, but quickly back to happy!!! :) Your post is wonderfully worded and clear. I will start digging into the WPF composition but at least I can understand what happens when I overwrite the templates assigned. Thank you.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, there are actually plenty of samples out there for styling, templates, triggers, dependencies, etc.. MS has plenty of default templates and styles to understand basic underlying components even getting into quite complex datagrid controls.

Comment: @DRapp But is there any detailed information about how Control.Template is actually implemented?

Comment: @Euphoric, if you are referring to full samples of control templates, Microsoft has them listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @DRapp No. I mean what happens to template after you assigning it to control. How it is rendered, how it is filled with data, how it gets into layout, etc..

Comment: That is more of Microsoft just applying a "Draw me like this" for the template.  The bindings come from the dependency properties that are available.  As for the layouts, did you look into any of the default templates from the link, such as textbox, buttons, etc?  The template has .xaml of all elements you want to have for borders, margins, colors, fonts, etc and can be fixed values or set via {Template Binding} values to go back to default properties sheet vs a hard-fixed value.  Am I missing something you are still looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I too had an early on learning of Templates.  [I posted a step-by-step answer to another question via a customized button control.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319)  The nice thing about that sample, you can build and play with styles and templates in a small project and see visual impact without requiring full project rebuild

Answer (score 1):

To start with, as you have mentioned that you do not have *Blend*. You can have Blend and install it with Visual Studio 2013 Community.

You can download this here if you do not have it already.

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

A part of the installation process, it allows you to select and install Blend. Also, the newer editions of visual studio give you some of the power of blend. In your design view you can right click on a control and create or copy a template.

On to the question.

As Euphoric has mentioned. Custom control authoring does require a little more in-depth knowledge of WPF, or any of the XAML frameworks. However, there are Visual Studio templates that can help you in the right direction.

As for the template naming, you have three types of templates you will come across in XAML. **ControlTemplate** (which for your purposes is the one we are interested in), **ItemsPanelTemplate** and **DataTemplate**. Again, as Euphoric has said, there are few circumstances where deriving a custom version of any of these three templates would bring anything to the table.

If you were to create a test WPF application, once you have created the basic project and solution. Go a head and add in another project, and from the templates VS provides, File -> Project -> New -> Windows Desktop. In the project template list, find *'WPF Custom Control Library'*. Once created, reference this project in your main *WPF* project.

This *custom control library* project will give you a skeleton setup for what you are looking for.

If you look in this project here are some things for you to note.

Firsty, you will find a folder called *Themes* and in there a file named *Generic.xaml*. In there you will see a style that has a setter setting the *Template* property. You will also see that both the *Style* and set *ControlTemplate* have a set *TargetType* that should be *local:CustomControl1*.

This is important as this is showing you how to create a custom controls default template. Now, to apply this template look in CustomControl1.cs and consider the following code.

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
```

For this control named *CustomControl1*, that template we looked at in the xaml will be automatically set as that controls default template where ever that control is used.

This project is a good starting point. But now you may want to override this ControlTemplate inside your main project. This is simple. I have code that looks something like this inside my main *WPF* project.

At the top of the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:CustomControl="clr-namespace:CustomControlTesting.CustomControlLibrary;assembly=CustomControlTesting.CustomControlLibrary"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

And in the body,

```
<CustomControl:CustomControl1>
     <CustomControl:CustomControl1.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl:CustomControl1}">
             <Grid>
                 <!-- Define my look to override the template -->
              </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
     </CustomControl:CustomControl1.Template>
</CustomControl:CustomControl1>
```

This is a brief overview and certainly misses out a lot. But I hope this is of help to you and can get you started.