# Xamarin Forms override Picker with custom ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I want to override the Xamarin Forms Control Picker so it display "No entries" if the binded collection is empty.

I tried:

```
<Picker
    x:Class="v.App.Styling.Controls.vPicker"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:v.App.Styling.Controls;assembly=v.App"
    x:Name="CustomPicker"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <Picker.Style>
        <Style TargetType="controls:vPicker">
            <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <controls:vStackLayout >
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                IsVisible="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, Converter={StaticResource HasItemsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

                            <controls:vEntry 
                                IsVisible="{Binding ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource HasNoItemsToBoolConverter}"
                                IsEnabled="False"
                                TextColor="{StaticResource ColorTextSecondary}"
                                Text="No entries"  />
                        </controls:vStackLayout>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Picker.Style>
</Picker>
```

But I get

```
      Error XFC0001: Cannot resolve property "ControlTemplate" on type "vPicker (property missing or missing accessors)". (13, 21)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I would have two controls, and the Visibility based on a setting on the MVVM you are binding to.  If no records vs has records.  Those properties made bindable via {get;set;} and each control respectively set visibility to it.

Comment: That's what I have right now, but I'd prefer a Custom Control so I just have to write the logic once.

Answer (score 0):

**Update here**

You could use a ContentView to write a custom control, as the picker doesn't have a **ControlTemplate** property. You could create your own custom picker view using ContentView, such like this:

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PickerControlTemplate74952715.PickerView"
    x:Name="PickerView">
<ContentView.Content>
    ...
    <controls:vStackLayout >
        <ContentPresenter 
            IsVisible="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, Converter={StaticResource HasItemsToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />

        <controls:vEntry 
            IsVisible="{Binding ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource HasNoItemsToBoolConverter}"
            IsEnabled="False"
            TextColor="{StaticResource ColorTextSecondary}"
            Text="No entries"  />
    </controls:vStackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

For more info, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template) and [Create a custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#create-a-custom-control)

===============

you could use data bindings to make it.

In the .xaml for Picker:

```
<Picker x:Name="picker"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
        IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
        Title="Select a monkey"
        TitleColor="Red">         
</Picker>
```

And in ViewModel just add some logic like this:

```
public Command ClickedCommand  // i define a button to add item to ItemCollection as a demo
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            ItemCollection.Add(count);
            count++;
            if(ItemCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                IsVisible = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319) that I offered someone trying to create their own style, but for a button. The underlying premise is the same.  You have something special you want to do based on a default class (or derived).

I would take the picker control, subclass it and add your own dependency property boolean or visibility so it can be used within your own custom style template.  A dependency property is instance specific, so if you had one picker that HAD entries, its flag would be different than another that had NO entries.

Now, that said,
[Here is one source to start about your own templates / styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0)

But this one [goes into an elaborate control template for a picker.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) You could build your own simplified and have your visible vs not context defined once as a style.  Then when you define your combobox picker control, just have it reference the given style you declare.  Having this style in a ResourceDictionary and available system wide can help all instances have the same look and feel without duplicating all over.

Comment: Well wpf is not the same as Xamarin or am I wrong? I do know how to make a custom control in WPF but can't transfer that to Xamarin.

Comment: @HFrisch, ahhh.. my bad, missed the Xamarin part.  I will try to look and get back.