# Changing one part of WPF Basedon Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three buttons that contain a `StackPanel` with a textbox and an image. I want to create a single default `Style`, then use three different Styles `BasedOn` the default to change the text in the `TextBlock` and the `Image Source`. This is what I have, but the text and image doesn't show up on the buttons. I'm not getting any errors, but the buttons are just blank.

```xml
    <Style x:Key="LogButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="26.4" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,17,0,17" />
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding CsvDisplayPath}" Width="15"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="CsvLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Log Csv Data" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding CsvDisplayPath}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RawLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Log Raw Data" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding RawDisplayPath}" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="PmdaLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Log PMDA Data" />
        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding PmdaDisplayPath}" />
    </Style>
```

And in the xaml:

```xml
<Button x:Name="Button_LogCsv" Command="{Binding LogCsvClick}" Style="{StaticResource CsvLogButton}" />
<Button x:Name="Button_LogRaw" Command="{Binding LogRawClick}" Style="{StaticResource RawLogButton}" />
<Button x:Name="Button_LogPmda" Command="{Binding LogPmdaClick}" Style="{StaticResource PmdaLogButton}" />
```

How can I get the correct content to populate the TextBlock and the Image?

Comment: Whatever view-model exposes the properties `PmdaDisplayPath`, `RawDisplayPath` and `CsvDisplayPath` could also expose button Text properties that your text box could bind to.  Or, if there are 3 separate view-model types then it sounds like what you want is implicit `DataTemplate` s and to make your button content be the view-model.
If they are all one view-model type, then you could have key-ed `DataTemplate` and have the style specify the `Button` 's `ContentDataTemplate` property

Comment: Thank you.  I think a `DataTemplate` is what I need. The text will never change on a single button, so I just want to do it all in xaml.

Comment: If you like to eliminate duplicate code you should extend Button to create a custom e.g. ImageButton. This button would have a Text property and ImageSource property. Then add a the text site and image host to the ControlTemplate of the ImageButton and bind them to the new properties. This avoids a lot of duplicate code and instead gives you a convenient and reusable control. No individual styling required only to set individual values on template elements.

Comment: May consider creating your own bindable properties and using them in your style definition.  Offer from a previous question, yours not AS complex, but also based on a button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274956/wpf-custom-button-best-approach/13276319#13276319

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `Button` control has no `TextBlock.Text` or `Image.Source` that you can set in a `Style`.

You could create a custom `Button` control with custom properties:

```
public class LogButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageSource),typeof(LogButton));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(LogButton));

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**Styles:**

```
<StackPanel x:Key="content" x:Shared="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid Width="150">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:LogButton}}"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" 
               Source="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:LogButton}}"
               Width="15" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
<Style x:Key="LogButtons" TargetType="{x:Type local:LogButton}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26.4" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,17,0,17" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource content}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CsvLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type local:LogButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Log Csv Data" />
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding CsvDisplayPath}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RawLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type local:LogButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Log Raw Data" />
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding RawDisplayPath}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PmdaLogButton" TargetType="{x:Type local:LogButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LogButtons}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Log PMDA Data" />
    <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding PmdaDisplayPath}" />
</Style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:LogButton x:Name="Button_LogCsv" Command="{Binding LogCsvClick}" Style="{StaticResource CsvLogButton}" />
<local:LogButton x:Name="Button_LogRaw" Command="{Binding LogRawClick}" Style="{StaticResource RawLogButton}" />
<local:LogButton x:Name="Button_LogPmda" Command="{Binding LogPmdaClick}" Style="{StaticResource PmdaLogButton}" />
```